# Keyboard / mouse event timing issues in Java code

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, synchronization, mouseevent

I'm currently working on my first GUI program, and there's one issue I do not know how to solve - I've provided a minimal (non-compilable) example below.

The problem is that, in some cases, if the delete key is pressed shortly after the mouse click which should change `activeElement`, the key action is executed before `activeElement` has been changed to the new value. How can I ensure that the code in `actionPerformed` waits for `activeElement` to be changed by `mouseClicked`?

---

```
public class Problem extends JPanel implements MouseListener{
    Element activeElement = null;

    public Problem(){
        super();
        this.addMouseListener(this);
        InputMap im = getInputMap(WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
        ActionMap am = getActionMap();
        im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_DELETE,0),"test");
        am.put("test",new AbstractAction(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
                if(activeElement!=null){
                    doSomethingWith(activeElement);
                    repaint();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me){
        activeElement = getElementByCoordinates(me.getX(),me.getY());
    }

    private Element getElementByCoordinates(int x, int y){
        [...]
    }

    private void doSomethingWith(Element e){
        [...]
    }
}
```

Comment: Reset the value to `null` when it's no longer needed

Comment: @MadProgrammer I can't, need it for the `paint` method and subsequent keystrokes. The main question boils down to: "how can I make sure that if a keystroke closely follows a click, `mouseClicked` is executed before the the keystroke takes effect?"

Comment: I suspect it would be sufficient to enclose the body of your actionPerformed method in [EventQueue.invokeLater](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/EventQueue.html#invokeLater-java.lang.Runnable-), so it will execute after all pending input events have been processed.

Comment: @vgr Since both actions occur with the EDT, I find it difficult to understand why there'd be a race condition at all, but that's me

Comment: Since both the mouse listener and the key binding are executed in the EDT, I find it hard to understand how they couldn't be executed sequentially. Perhaps a better runnable example which could used to test the issue would help.

Comment: @MadProgrammer I agree.  Makes me wonder what’s in the getElementByCoordinates method.

Comment: @VGR tried it, but it doesn't change a thing, the timing problems still occur. (And I ruled out hardware issues - clicks/keystrokes timed the same way in a text editor don't exhibit this behavior.)

Comment: @VGR basically, "for all `Element e` in `keySet()` of `Map<Element,Path2D> m`, if `m.get(e).contains(x,y)`, then `return e;`".

Comment: Is there any code in your mousePressed and mouseReleased methods?

Comment: @VGR no, there isn't

Comment: @VGR ooooh... I see the problem now! It occurs if I do not release the mouse before the key event! Feeling stupid now for not noticing this myself... thanks!

Comment: @VGR changed `mouseClicked` to `mousePressed`, program works as intended now :)

Comment: @VGR Nice spot! Post that as an answer, I'd like to up-vote that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mouseClicked` is called after you have pressed and the released the mouse in (nearly) the same location.  If you type your key before releasing the mouse, the InputMap will be triggered before mouseClicked is called.

To register a mouse press before the key is pressed, regardless of whether the mouse button has been released, place your code in `mousePressed` rather than mouseClicked.